# Simple HTML DOM Parser find closest Element

Tags: php, dom

I want to find the "nearest Element" for a specific String using (simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net)

For example, if I search for the word "Imprint" I want to get the nearest element over it, therefore I programmed a "recursive function"

```
function getelementofcontent($html,$search){
    for($i=0;strpos($html->childNodes($i)->plaintext,$search)==-1;$i++);
    getelementofcontent($html->childNodes($i),$search);
}
```

So the method is always called when there is still the string... what did I do wrong?

Comment: "nearest element over it," means what? Parent? or completely unrelated element?

Comment: Sounds like you would like to get the parent element of the text node containing the word imprint. Easy to do with Xpath but not possible with CSS selectors. https://eval.in/162471

Comment: But i dont only want to search for a , i want to find any kind of element and get the "deepest" ones,...

Comment: https://eval.in/162664